# Inkscape is not opening (I am currently using manjaro linux)

Tags: linux, archlinux, inkscape, manjaro

I tried to open Inkscape via gui icon but it's not opening

when i am trying to open it via CLI this was the output

```
$inkscape
inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.118: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I actually searched on the internet but could not resolve it with those explanations.

these are some more information

```
$which inkscape
/usr/bin/inkscape
```

```
$pacman -Q poppler inkscape

poppler 21.11.0-1
inkscape 1.1.2-1
```

```
$ldd $(which inkscape) | fgrep libpoppler
    libpoppler.so.118 => not found
    libpoppler-glib.so.8 => /usr/bin/../lib/inkscape/../libpoppler-glib.so.8 (0x00007fafaaa28000)
    libpoppler.so.115 => /usr/bin/../lib/inkscape/../libpoppler.so.115 (0x00007fafa8a8e000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still in the need of help but I had the same problem and found out that installing `poppler-glib` saved my install of inkscape.